# convert Vertex buffer to Vertex array

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo, vao

I'm working on OpenGL program and I must calculate a bounding box . I made the code to do it but I can't get vertexes coordinations from vertex buffer . Someone can explain me an easy way to get data from vertex buffer?
I'm using Java for android and OpenGL es

Comment: Downloading vertex data from the GPU like this every frame is likely to be slow. Try keeping a local copy of the vertex info.

Answer (score 1):

If you use OpenGL ES 3.0 or later, you can use `glMapBufferRange()` to access buffer data directly. See the [man page](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) for details about the functionality, and the [GLES30 documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES30.html#glMapBufferRange(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for details about the Java bindings in Android.

I don't think there's any reasonable way to do this in ES 2.0. I could think of absolutely awful ways, but I would feel bad to steer you in that direction. Well, for completeness, but please **do not do this**: You could render something that ends up leaving the vertex data in a render target, and read it back with `glReadPixels()`.

If you need frequent access to the vertex data in your own code, it will most likely work better if you keep a copy of it. You already had the data when you called `glBufferData()`. If you're currently throwing it away after the `glBufferData()` call, simply keep it around, and use it whenever you need access to vertex data.

Comment: I have to calculate a bounding box and i tried to read the vertex buffer of a subset and I get an error of accessibility. So I want to try with the vertex array but it is in a part of code that isn't mine so I can't put my code there so easily

Comment: I would try with glbufferdata()

Answer (score 0):

i've found how to do it

```
    mFb= (FloatBuffer)    vb.getData(UlVertexBuffer.VERTEX_FIELD_POSITION).position(0);
    getmFloatArray(mFb);
    mSb= (ShortBuffer) ib.getData();
    getmShortArray(mSb);
```